# if condition helper hits when && included

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, helper

I am using handlebars and creating my view. I have registered a helper for `if-else` condition from of the SO posts which is as below:

```
helpers.ifCond = function (v1, operator, v2, options) {
  var cond = false;
  switch(operator) {
    case '!=':
      cond = (v1 != v2); break;
    case '==':
      cond = (v1 == v2); break;
    case '===':
      cond = (v1 === v2); break;
    case '<':
      cond = (v1 < v2); break;
    case '<=':
      cond = (v1 <= v2); break;
    case '>':
      cond = (v1 > v2); break;
    case '>=':
      cond = (v1 >= v2); break;
    case '&&':
      cond = (v1 && v2); break;
    case '||':
      cond = (v1 || v2); break;
  }

  if(cond) {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
}
```

It works well for single condition as in

```
{{#ifCond this.total "!=" 0}}{{this.total}}{{else}}0{{/ifCond}}
```

But when I include `&&` as below,

```
{{#ifCond this.total "!=" 0 '&&' this.total "!=" "null"}}
     {{this.total}}
{{else}}
     0
{{/ifCond}}
```

It throws me an exception saying `Error: Object && has no method 'fn'`.

Could not understand why this is failing here. Could someone please enlighten me on this?

Comment: '&&' is being passed as your `options` object. The function logic for handling `&&` isn't implemented properly - you have to evaluate the left, and if that's true, then evaluate the right and check if that's true. 

However, you should keep logic outside of your templates – then you don't have to come up with hacky solutions like this.

Comment: @RushyPanchal I got confused with the logic when `{{#ifCond this.firstName '||' this.lastName }}` works..

Comment: There's a significant difference between `this.total "!=" 0 '&&' this.total "!=" "null"` and `this.firstName '||' this.lastName `; the first requires three evaluations (`a = total != 0`, `b = total != null`, `a && b`) whereas the second requires just one (`firstName || lastName`).

Your helper function can handle the second form with `||` because it does not need to evaluate the two arguments – it can just perform the comparison. However, it cannot handle the first because there is further evaluation that you have not implemented.